# Power Query return 404 on Odata v4 endpoints

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

I'm using

- Excel 2013 version: 15.0.4737.1001
- Power Query version: 2.22.4007.242
- Microsoft.AspNet.OData version: 5.6.0

When I add a new OData feed with https://localhost:44300/odata then it findes the list of controllers just fine. But each of them return 404 DataSource.NotFound.

[image]

Everything works fine in POSTMAN :/

Comment: Does it work fine in postman with the port that it specifies there?

Comment: There's an update out for PowerQuery - version 2.24.4064.242. Notes say that it improves OData connections.

Comment: Updating to 2.24.4064.242 fixed it